# How to .gitignore app/app.iml in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gitignore

No matter how I structure my .gitignore I can't seem to ignore app/app.iml via Android Studio 2.0.0.

So far, I've tried ignoring all *.iml files per the github's standard Android Studio .gitignore template, as well as targeting the file directly..

```
app/app.iml
*.iml
```

Anybody run into a similar issue with this specific file or other *.iml files? How did you resolve it?

Comment: This *should* work. Did you previously add it? If so, did you remove it from the index?

Comment: Are you adding the gitignore after you already committed the file(s)?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak *it* being what precisely? Our Android directory setup might be the culprit. We have an 'app' directory inside our Android Studio project and when I'm inside of Android Studio, it seems to think there is an *additional* child directory with the same name *app/* just below the parent despite the fact that the child app directory with the same name does not exist.

Comment: @cricket_007 the app.iml file had been committed a long time ago. I am not adding a new app.iml file as its being generated automatically by Android Studio.

Comment: If it's already been committed, then you have to remove it from the Git cache before it can be ignored correctly

Comment: @cricket_007 below, @kurtacious suggested running the following command `git rm --cached app/app.iml`. Would that do the trick? While I've already solved the issue, I you're right in saying that uncaching the file would've worked as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding a forward slash to `app/app.iml` inside your .gitignore like so.. `/app/app.iml`. This worked for me after following @xiaoyaoworm' advice.

Answer (score 24):

If the files were already committed before the gitignore update, it would continue to be tracked by git.

Try doing a `git rm --cached app/app.iml` and follow that with another commit removing the file.

Comment: I think i've already figured out the issue. However, I tried this anyway and interestingly .git thinks this file was deleted. This could be an alternative solution following the update to the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 5):

Try these steps:

1. Remove cached iml files, use: `git rm --cached <all_your_iml_files>`
2. Add `*.iml` in `.gitignore` file and commit again.

The iml files will not be tracked after this.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you have done should work. Give a try on installing .ignore plugin, right click on that file app.iml, there is a "Add to ignore file".

Comment: I did as you instructed and the plugin added `/app/app.iml` to my .gitignore file with the backlash at the start being the new addition. Also might be worth mentioning Android Studio threw the following error after following your instructions `.ignore threw an uncaught EmptyThrowable.` with the option to disable the .ignore plugin. With that said, this seemed to work! Thanks!